# Is there a way to force ArcCatalog to use a specific tessellation scheme for a SQL Server spatial index?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql-server, arccatalog, spatial-index

If I Recalculate a spatial index from ArcCatalog, the tessellation scheme is always set to "Geometry Grid". Even when the previous index was Geometry auto grid. ArcCatalog always changes it back.

Is there a way to specify the tessellation from ArcCatalog? Alternatively, can SQL Server default to a specific tessellation scheme?

*Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 SP1*

Answer (score 2):

I just went through a week of back-and-forth with ESRI Tech Support about this issue. I have found two parameters in the Defaults Keyword in the dbtune table:

```
Parameter: A_MS_SPINDEX; Value: "GRIDS = (MEDIUM, MEDIUM, MEDIUM, MEDIUM), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16"
Parameter: B_MS_SPINDEX; Value: "GRIDS = (MEDIUM, MEDIUM, MEDIUM, MEDIUM), CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16"
```

One modifies the "ADDS" table default spatial index and the other modifies the "DELETES" table spatial index. I tried removing the value in each of these since the default for SQL Server 2012 is the GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID. This didn't work. The Analyst at ESRI contacted a developer. The developer said "he wouldn't recommend using GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID as the default." I asked him to confirm that he essentially meant that they hadn't programmed the dbtune table to allow for that. He agreed on that being the case.

I therefore posted an [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/ideas/9559) requesting that the option to use GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID for the spatial index and to allow it to be used by default. I am guessing it is only a matter of time before they realize what they are missing but just in case, go promote the idea.